# I need to fetch data and make an API from a pre existing schema in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose, backend, rest

I need to fetch data and make an API from a pre existing schema in mongoDB, using  mongoose to update the total no. of orders in my dashboard..do I just have to import the schema page to my api page? Or what..? .I am new at coding..help would be much appreciated.

```
    enter code here
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let orderPlaced = new Schema({
    userID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default:null},
    shortOrderID: {type: String, required: false, default:null},
    sellerID:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    product: [{
        productID:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default:null}, 
        variantID:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default:null}, 
        inventoryID:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default:null}, 
        quantity:{type: Number, required: true, default:0},
        sellerID:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default:null},
        }],
    discount : {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},
    totalAmount: {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},  
    tipAmount: {type: Number, required: false, default: 0},
    tax : {type:Number,required : false,default : 0},
    deliveryCharges : {type : Number,required : false,default : 0},
    paidAmount : {type:Number,required : false,default : 0},
    specialInstruction:{type: String, required: false, default: null},
    addressID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, default: null},
    paymentID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false,  default: null},
    status: {type: String, required: false,  default: "INCOMPLETE",},
    paymentSuccess: {type: Boolean, required: false,  default: false},
    shippingAssignment: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, default: null},
    contactNumber: {type: String, required: false, default: null},
    tenantId: {type: String, required: true, default: "self"},
    applicationId: {type: String, required: true, default: 'self'},
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

This is the scheme from where I have to fetch order placed data and add to my other restapi..how would I do that?